# How can I use this Python module code from github in my project?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I can't figure out how to setup paths and import statements for this code to use it in my project:

```
https://github.com/IssamLaradji/NeuralNetworks
```

I added the code as a git submodule so here is the root folder :

```
NeuralNetworks/
train_mlp.py
```

Then in my python code, I tried to import like this:

```
from NeuralNetworks.multilayer_perceptron import multilayer_perceptron
from NeuralNetworks.multilayer_perceptron import base

mlp = multilayer_perceptron.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50, 20), max_iter=200, alpha=0.02)
```

Python is complaining that the "base" module is not available. How can I set up this submodule to work in my `sklearn` project?

Comment: the right way would be to submit a pull request with a simple `setup.py` that would allow to `pip install` the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You could use git to clone it onto your local system if it is not available through pypi; or

2) There is a download button at github that will give you a zip or tar file that you can download and place under your project and use locally.

THe examples there show how you can just run scripts in the same directory, by importing multilayer_perceptron.py.  If you want to package things up as a Python package, you will need to add the `__init__.py` and all that stuff and make sure things still import by yourself.

Alternatively, you can use add the directory containing this stuff to your path, either through sys.path or the environment variables.

Edit:  To reflect the updated question, you will need `__init__.py` in the submodule.

Since you know git, I would first submit a pull request to get this into the upstream project (it is an innocuous change that doesn't require major reorganization of the project).

Until that happens, you have one of two choices:

1) Your code could add the subdirectory to sys.path and then access the python modules directly (not as submodules).

2) You could add a snippet of code in a module you define that would write the `__init__.py` into the git submodule:

```
import os
mydir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
initf = os.path.join(mydir, 'NeuralNetworks', '__init__.py')
if not os.path.exists(initf):
    open(initf, 'wb').close()
```

When you import this module, it will turn NeuralNetworks into a Python package, by creating the `__init__.py` module.

Comment: thanks for your help. It was late and I should have been more clear. Please see my edits. I want to keep my project clean and not have my files saved within this submodule.

Comment: I didn't get it going with method two. Method one is working this way: `sys.path.append("NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron")`